# What is difference between dir and dir/ in linux terminal or in dos?

Tags: linux, unix, command, dos

For Example : In any command when we need to refer any directory. Then we use `dirname` or `dirname/`

what is the difference between them?

For e.g. `cd dirname`  vs `cd dirname/`

and `cp -R dirname1 dirname2` vs `cp -R dirname1 dirname2/` vs `cp -R dirname1/ dirname2/`

Comment: Could you show the command you are trying?

Comment: If you have a symlink called `foo` which links to a directory `bar/`, `ls foo` will show `foo` while `ls foo/` will show the contents of `bar/`. As the others stated there are some other occasions when the difference matters. In most cases you won't notice. Other example: When having a file called `directory` (somebody made a mistake, created a file that is expected to be a directory) `mv somefile directory` will silently overwrite the file. But `mv somefile directory/` will complain that `directory` is no directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirname` is the directory. `dirname\` is a path whose last node is the directory.

In *most* contexts you can get away with using either, but that's not always the case.

Usually if you're trying to, say, copy a file into a directory, `cp file dirname\` to make clear that you're copying it to a new path. Visualise `file` being appended to the path, to become `dirname\file`. This is most important when working with symbolic links, as the file system isn't *quite* as clever at auto-translating `dirname` to `dirname\` as required, when `dirname` is a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

For linux shell: In general, either one will work.  Assuming the two filenames actually are directories, including or omitting the final slash should be optional.

Cases where you might notice a difference:

- if dirname is actually a symbolic link to a directory, using the final / will fail
- a few commands, like rsync, specifically treat filename arguments ending with / differently

Answer (score 0):

At least in a DOS/Windows shell, there usually is no difference. There is one exception I know:

If you use

```
xcopy somefile C:\somepath
```

and `somepath` doesn't exist, xcopy asks if `somepath` is a file or a directory to be created, which can be avoided using

```
xcopy somefile C:\somepath\
```

which will just create `somepath` and copy `somefile` in there.

So in that case, `somepath\` makes it clearer that it's a path. Anyway, usually you're referring to a path that already exists, so there'll be no difference between the two cases.

Comment: You can  also look at the _Window_'s  "[robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc733145.aspx)" command.